# Joining 3 tables and grouping by max column value

Tags: sql-server

Thanks for the answers to my previous question.  I hope it's okay to do this but I now have another related question:

I have now been asked to extend what I'm doing to include a conversion of a GrossCost which is held in local currency to a base currency of GBP.

I have the SQL for both parts individually, but don't know how to combine them.  The two parts are:

1. Get the sum of GrossCost for each company:

   `Select Cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Sum(JobCosting.PurchaseOrderItems.GrossCost) Desc) AS Int) As 'RowNum', 
   Admin.Companies.UniqueName As 'UN',
   Sum(JobCosting.PurchaseOrderItems.GrossCost) As 'DonutValue'
   From Admin.Companies
   Inner Join JobCosting.PurchaseOrders On Admin.Companies.CompanyId =
   JobCosting.PurchaseOrders.SupplierCompanyId
   Inner Join JobCosting.PurchaseOrderItems
   On JobCosting.PurchaseOrders.PurchaseOrderId =
   JobCosting.PurchaseOrderItems.PurchaseOrderId
   Where UniqueName Like 'HH %'
   Group By UniqueName
   Order By 'DonutValue' Desc`
2. Get the Currency Conversion Rate for each currency. Conversion is GrossCost * Exchange Rate for the relevant currency.  This is the Exchange Rate SQL (provided by SQLGRL - thanks again):

   ```
   SELECT    *
   FROM (SELECT  CompanyId, UniqueName,CurrencyCode,ExchangeRate,FromCurrencyID, ToCurrencyId, ActiveDate,  
   rank() OVER 
   (partition BY  UniqueName,Admin.Currencies.CurrencyId
   ORDER BY ActiveDate DESC) AS Rank
   FROM  Admin.Companies
   INNER JOIN Admin.Currencies 
   ON Admin.Companies.CurrencyId = Admin.Currencies.CurrencyId 
   INNER JOIN   Admin.CurrencyRates 
   ON Admin.Currencies.CurrencyId = Admin.CurrencyRates.FromCurrencyId
   WHERE Admin.CurrencyRates.ToCurrencyId = 47) ci
   ```

   WHERE     ci.Rank = 1

What I need to do is end up with a combined SQL that gets all the same rows back and calculates the converted value of the sum of GrossSales for each company.

Again, any help would be very gratefully received, as I'm really stuck.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this -

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT c.*, --column_list
    ROW_NUMBER(ORDER BY cur_from.ActiveDate desc) row_num 
    FROM Company c 
    INNER JOIN Currencies cu ON c.CurrencyId = cu.CurrencyId
    INNER JOIN CurrencyRates cu_from ON cu.CurrencyId = cu_from.CurrencyFromId 
    -- WHERE CONDITION if any
)

SELECT * FROM cte WHERE row_num = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the most current rate of exchange for each currency code for each company:

```
SELECT    *
    FROM (SELECT  CompanyName,CurrencyCode,ExchangeRate3,ActiveDate,  
    rank() OVER 
    (partition BY  CompanyName,dbo.Currencies.CurrencyId
    ORDER BY ActiveDate DESC) AS Rank
    FROM  dbo.company 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Currencies 
    ON dbo.company.CurrencyId = dbo.Currencies.CurrencyId 
    INNER JOIN   dbo.CurrencyRates 
    ON dbo.Currencies.CurrencyId = dbo.CurrencyRates.CurrencyFromId) ci
WHERE     ci.Rank = 1
```

**EDIT to include additional information requested:**

```
with cte as (
Select Cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
(ORDER BY Sum(JobCosting.PurchaseOrderItems.GrossCost) Desc) AS Int) As 'RowNum', 
Admin.Companies.UniqueName As 'UN', 
Sum(JobCosting.PurchaseOrderItems.GrossCost) As 'DonutValue' 
From Admin.Companies 
Inner Join JobCosting.PurchaseOrders 
On Admin.Companies.CompanyId = JobCosting.PurchaseOrders.SupplierCompanyId 
Inner Join JobCosting.PurchaseOrderItems 
On JobCosting.PurchaseOrders.PurchaseOrderId  =JobCosting.PurchaseOrderItems.PurchaseOrderId 
Where UniqueName Like 'HH %' Group By UniqueName Order By 'DonutValue' Desc
)

SELECT    *
FROM (SELECT  CompanyId, UniqueName,CurrencyCode,ExchangeRate,FromCurrencyID, 
ToCurrencyId, ActiveDate,  
rank() OVER 
(partition BY  UniqueName,Admin.Currencies.CurrencyId
ORDER BY ActiveDate DESC) AS Rank
FROM  Admin.Companies
INNER JOIN Admin.Currencies 
ON Admin.Companies.CurrencyId = Admin.Currencies.CurrencyId 
INNER JOIN   Admin.CurrencyRates 
ON Admin.Currencies.CurrencyId = Admin.CurrencyRates.FromCurrencyId
WHERE Admin.CurrencyRates.ToCurrencyId = 47) as ci
INNER JOIN   cte
on cte.UN = ci.UniqueName
where    ci.Rank = 1;
```

This solution uses a common table expression.  But you could achieve the same result by creating a view and joining the view to the ranking query.

Comment: The challenge has extended after your help and I'm stuck again.  Any help would be gratefully received.